# How to use a Oracle database in ASP.NET without Entity Framework?

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oracle

Can someone tell me in a simple way, how can I use an Oracle DB in my ASP.NET MVC 5 project?  I have tried different articles but I didn't get a clear answer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is the simple way to do this:

```
using System.Data.OracleClient;

        public string GetConnectionString()
        {
            String connString = "SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=YourHostName)(PORT=YourPort))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=YourServiceName)));uid=YourUserId;pwd=YourPassword;";
            return connString;
        }

        public void ConnectingToOracle()
        {
            string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
            using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection())
            {
                connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

                connection.Open();

                OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                string sql = "select * from MyDatabase where name like '%John Paul%'";
                command.CommandText = sql;

                OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string myField = (string)reader["address"]; //Get the address of John Paul
                }
            }
        }
```